# jquery toggle tabs hide active class when clicking same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

when i click tab 1, 1 content show and active tab class is added.

when i click tab 2, 1 content hides remove tab active class and 2 content show and adds tab active class

but the effect i want is when i click tab 1, 1 content show, click again tab 1 content hides but the tab active class doesn't remove.

Any suggest will be help thanks

```
<div id="tabs_container">
   <ul class="tabs">
     <li>
       <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab">Option 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab">Option 2</a>
     </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_contents_container">    
      <div id="tab_1_contents" class="tab_content tab_contents_active">
         Option 1 stuff     
      </div>

      <div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_content">'
         Option 2 stuff</div>
      </div>

     </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.tab-content').hide();

  $('.tab').click(function() {
     var target = $(this.rel);          
        $('.tab-content').not(target).hide();
        target.toggle();

  $('#tabs_container > .nav-tabs > li.tabActive')
      .removeClass('tabActive');

  $(this).parent().addClass('tabActive');

  $('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active')
      .removeClass('tab_contents_active'); 

  $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Just `target.show();` instead of `target.toggle();`

Comment: doesn't work, my jQuery skills are 0, i copy this code from another post, everything works I only want to add the option that when I click the same tab the content is hiding and the active class else remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `target.show();` instead of `target.toggle();`. `.toggle()` will `show()/hide()` elements based on its current `visibility`

Also correct `typo`. You are using `-` instead of `_` while selecting items.

```js
$('.tab_content').hide(); //typo here!
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $('.tab_content').hide();
  var target = $(this.rel);
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('tabActive')) {
    target.hide();
    $(this).parent().removeClass('tabActive');
  } else {
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('tabActive');
    target.show();
    $(this).parent().addClass('tabActive');
  }
});
```

```css
.tabActive {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs_container">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab">Option 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_contents_container">
    <div id="tab_1_contents" class="tab_content">
      Option 1 stuff
    </div>

    <div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_content">Option 2 stuff</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: now the content is not hiding when clicking the same tab and the tab active class also is not removing.

Comment: Thanks for your time but is not working, because when I click tab 1 the content shows, but when I click tab 1 again the content shroud hide and the .tabActive (orange background) should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `.toggleClass();`

```
$('#tabs_container > .nav-tabs > li.tabActive').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('tabActive');
$(this).parent().toggleClass('tabActive');
```

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
     var target = $(this.rel);

  $('#tabs_container li').not($(this).parent()).removeClass('tabActive');

  $(this).parent().toggleClass('tabActive');

  $('#tabs_container > .tab_contents_container > div').not($(target)).removeClass('tab_contents_active'); 
  $(target).toggleClass('tab_contents_active');
 }).eq(0).click();
```

```css
.tabActive{
  background : #005eff;
  padding : 5px;
  
}
.tabActive > a{
  color :#fff;
}

.tab_content{
  display : none;
}

.tab_contents_active{
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs_container">
   <ul class="tabs">
     <li>
       <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab">Option 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab">Option 2</a>
     </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_contents_container">    
      <div id="tab_1_contents" class="tab_content">
         Option 1 stuff     
      </div>

      <div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_content">
         Option 2 stuff
      </div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is not work, my jQuery skills are 0, I click the same tab again and the content is hiding but the active class from the tab is not removing.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of your code:

```js
  $('.tab').click(function() {
    $('.tab_content').removeClass('tab_contents_active');
    $(this.rel).addClass("tab_contents_active");
  });
```

```css
.tab_content { display:none;}
.tab_content.tab_contents_active { display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs_container">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#" rel="#tab_1_contents" class="tab">Option 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" rel="#tab_2_contents" class="tab">Option 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_contents_container">
    <div id="tab_1_contents" class="tab_content tab_contents_active">
      Option 1 stuff
    </div>

    <div id="tab_2_contents" class="tab_content">
      Option 2 stuff</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```